# Is it possible to send files and folders from FTP to Azure blob storage in timely basis?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

i am trying to copy files from FTP to Azure Storage using logic apps, my app was fully functional when a file is getting added in the ftp location but not folders. i dont see any settings to change to copy the folders also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, I think yes. I have created a simple demo, I could send the files and folders to  Azure Blob Storage timely basis.
You could refer to my steps.

1. Logic app>Logic App Designer>choose trigger ‘FTP – When a file is added or modified’.

In **Connection**:

The Connection name: FTP Server name.

The Server Address: I copy from App Service>Properties>FTP HOST NAME.

The User Name: App service name/ FTP Server name. I copy from App Service>Properties> FTP/Deployment User.

In  **setting**:

I choose one folder in FTP (‘/LogFiles/application’ folder).

Frequency: 3 minutes.

[image]
2.  Click Add an Action> Search Azure Blob Storage-Create Blob:

In **Connection**:

Connection Name: Any name you created( such as 'ftpconnect').

In **setting**:

I could create a blog file to store logs in Action Blob 1. And I could send a folder from FTP to Azure Blob in Action Blob 2.
[image]

Since I choose the ‘/LogFiles/application’ folder in FTP, so every time I trace the application logs, the FTP would store these logs in folder.

Finally, I trace my application logs in application and click run in Logic App Designer, It works fine. You could see the file in folder from the following screenshot.

In Azure Blob Storage:
[image]

Besides, you could also refer to this [article](http://mythoughtlab.azurewebsites.net/azure/using-logic-apps-to-transfer-files-from-ftp-into-azure-blob-storage/) to learn how to copy files from FTP to Blob Storage in Logic App.

Comment: So this creates a folder that was already in present in FTP to the Azure Storage, but my requirement is that there are chances that the folders are added in the ftp location daily with a different name and also files within those folders.

Comment: In my step 1, I choose '/LogFiles/application' folder in FTP. And you can see all files in this file path have been copied to Azure Storage. So you also  just enter '/' in textbox, then all folders and files in FTP would be added to Azure Storage.

Comment: I did just as you mentioned , and it is working fine till there are files added in the application folder, but when i start adding folders withing the application folder then the logic app is not copying those folders to the storage. I even tried using '/' at the ftp folder level and that too copies only the files but not folders.

Comment: I also test it on my side, the result is same as you.  And I read this 
 url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp.  The FTP trigger all just mentioned file layer. So I suppose the official does not yet support the folder layer.